# Find Count From Other Table in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a problem in sequelize with node js. I want product count according to category.

My category model is define as:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../configs/db-connection.config');
const Product = require('../models/product.model');
const Category = sequelize.define(
  'category',
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
Category.hasMany(Product);
Product.belongsTo(Category);
module.exports = Category;
```

My product model is define as:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../configs/db-connection.config');
const Product = sequelize.define(
  'product',
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    categoryRef: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      foreignKey: true,
      references: {
        model: CATEGORY.TABLE_NAME,
        key: 'id'
      }
    }   
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = Product;
```

Here each category is connected to product as a foreignKey in product model like categoryRef.
Let me give you an example one category is Devices and its product will be Laptop, Monitor, CPU etc. If devices have 3 products then it will return 3 as a count in category.
Here each object in array represents to category obj and I want to add an extra field i.e. count in category obj and it will give me the count of products which is stored as a foreignKey in product table.

My expected result is:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Devices',
    createdAt: '2020-01-17T12:08:10.000Z',
    updatedAt: '2020-01-17T12:11:22.000Z',
    count:3
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'appliances',
    createdAt: '2020-01-23T07:59:27.000Z',
    updatedAt: '2020-01-23T08:12:54.000Z',
    count:0
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'furniture',
    createdAt: '2020-01-23T08:51:35.000Z',
    updatedAt: '2020-01-23T08:51:35.000Z',
    count:0
  },
];
```

I already applied following sql query on database which gives perfect result:

```
SELECT inventory.categories.*, count(products.categoryRef) as count
from inventory.categories
left join inventory.products
on (inventory.categories.id = inventory.products.categoryRef)
group by
inventory.categories.id
```

But I don't know how to convert it into sequelize methods.
Please help me to find out the solution which methods I need to use to get the desired output.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `attributes` and `include` to get your category with counts of products associated with it

```
Category.findAll({
        attributes: {
          include: [
            [
              Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('products.categoryRef')),
              'productsCount'
            ]
          ]
        },
        include: [
          {
            model: Product,
            attributes: []
          }
        ],
        group: ['id']
      });
```

Comment: let me know if you have any query

Comment: It gives me this error:
In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'inventory.category.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Thanks bro now it's working.
Can you please tell me about the resource where I can learn sequelize?

Comment: let me know if you have any query

Comment: Hi sorry to say but the problem is not resolved yet, it gives me the error of Unknown column 'categoryId' in 'field list'
How to specify that we have key name of categoryRef in model not categoryId?

Comment: i think you have to use  categories.id instead of categorie.id in query

Comment: See this is the error:
Unknown column 'products.categoryId' in 'on clause'

Comment: Error: Unknown column 'product.id' in 'field list'

Comment: I got the solution actually, I forgot to add foreignKey associations in models.
Can you explain what is the use of constraints in models either it is true or false?

Comment: great keep it up

Comment: Can you tell me the usage of constraints field in models?

Comment: we are here using  categoryRef in our product model to reference category model like foreign key in sql table

Comment: main uses of constraints field is depending on which constraints field we are making here we are using foreign key, for define primary key field we need to use pk constraints   and so on